# dcgpofix "Could not open the Active Directory Object"

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am trying to run `dcgpofix` because my AD environment is a disaster. This organization had only one person in IT and he hired me to help, and shortly thereafter left. He left behind a corrupted domain to clean up, which I am now trying to do.

The Default Domain and Default Domain Controllers policies did not exist, but folders titled with their UIDs (`31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9` and `6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9` respectively) exist in `C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies` and `C:\Windows\SYSVOL\sysvol\my.domain\Policies` on both of my DCs. When trying to run `dcgpofix`, it gave the error:

```
the system cannot find the file specified
```

I opened ADSI Edit and created `groupPolicyContainers` with the CNs as listed above under `Default naming context > DC=mydomain,DC=mydomain > CN=System > CN=Policies`. Now I get the error in the title:

```
**Could not open the Active Directory Object LDAP://CN=Machine,CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=mydomain,DC=mydomain**
```

Obviously I have anonymized my `DC=` with `mydomain`, and the `CN={}` will have either UID, depending if I run `dcgpofix` with `/target:domain` or `/target:dc`.

I have tried opening the attribute editors for these `groupPolicyContainers` and adding the appropriate `gPCFileSysPaths` with the value `\\my.domain\\SYSVOL\my.domain\Policies\{corresponding_UID}` to no avail.

I cannot find anything about this on Google, if you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: spin up a domain controller in a test environment to see how the permissions and containers are setup in the default